# JNI - Instantiate Java ArrayList from C++ Vector

Tags: java, android, c++, arraylist, android-ndk

I am trying to create an `ArrayList` that contains a Java class by calling its methods using a native function. The java class `ExampleClass` looks as such:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    private int _exampleID;
    private String _exampleName;
    public ExampleClass(int exampleID, String exampleName) {
        _exampleID = exampleID;
        _exampleName = exampleName;
    }
}
```

On the native side I have a complimentary class `ExampleClass_Cpp` which is loaded into a vector. Here is the native implementation:

```
static thread_local JNIEnv* env;
static jclass java_util_ArrayList = static_cast<jclass>(env->NewGlobalRef(env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList")));
static jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_= env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "<init>", "(I)V");
jmethodID java_util_ArrayList_add = env->GetMethodID(java_util_ArrayList, "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V");

JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL cppv2javaAL(JNIEnv *env) {

    std::vector<ExampleClass_Cpp> vector;
    jclass J_Class_Example = env->FindClass("app/androidndkproject/ExampleClass");
    jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(J_Class_Example, "<init>", "(I)V");

    jobject result = env->NewObject(java_util_ArrayList, java_util_ArrayList_, vector.size());
    for (auto const &Ex: vector) {
        jobject J_Obj_Example = env->NewObject(J_Class_Example, methodId, Ex.getExampleID(), Ex.getExampleName());
        env->CallVoidMethod(result, java_util_ArrayList_add, J_Obj_Example);
        env->DeleteLocalRef(J_Obj_Example);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am having some difficulty with the corresponding JNI mapping. My present Java call, which I know is incorrect is as follows :
 `public native ArrayList<ExampleClass> cpp2java();`.

**What is the proper way to create an `ArrayList` through the JNI (or what is wrong with the above)? Should it be `jobjectArray`?**

If it was written in Java (the context I would like to use it) it would be:

`public List<ExampleClass> exampleList = new ArrayList<ExampleClass>();`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, ArrayList.add() returns boolean, you should use

```
CallBooleanMethod
```

Maybe there is a better way, but from my experience, you can

create an empty list in java

```
public List<ExampleClass> exampleList = new ArrayList<ExampleClass>()
```

pass exampleList as a reference to cpp, sth like:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL cppv2javaAL(JNIEnv *env, jobject jlist) {
...
env->CallBooleanMethod(jlist, java_util_ArrayList_add, J_Obj_Example);
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. How would you call to `cppv2javaAL` in Java? (`public native ...?... cppv2javaAL(exampleList);`

Comment: yes, just create a native java method that mapps cppv2javaAL

Comment: How in the world do you declare ** java_util_ArrayList** in JNI?